# Flatten list of JSONs stored in pandas cell

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, one of the columns contains list of JSONs stored as string and I am having trouble trying to flatten it to columns.

JSON column looks like this

```
[{'id':'item1','xp':'27097','lvl':'26','items':[]},
{'id':'item2','xp':'40650','lvl':'26','items':[]},
{'id':'item3','xp':'33900','lvl':'26','items':['item1', 'item2', 'item3']}]
```

Screenshot of DF here (can't place pic, not enought reputation) https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2b3X.png

json_normalize does not work here since it's a string nested in pandas dataframe

Expected result:

```
+-----------+-------+-----+-----+-----------------------------+
| player_id |  id   | xp  | lvl |            items            |
+-----------+-------+-----+-----+-----------------------------+
| id1       | item1 | 444 |  10 | []                          |
| id1       | item2 |  12 |  77 | []                          |
| id1       | item3 |  15 |  20 | ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'] |
+-----------+-------+-----+-----+-----------------------------+
```

For each id I would like to flatten this list to columns and get list if items and its parameters.

The code below works fine for a single JSON, not for list:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x)[0] for x in original_df.pop('items')])
         .add_prefix('items.'))
```

Comment: Instead of link to screenshot of `DF`, paste some sample data of `DF`

Comment: How is your original `player_id` DataFrame formatted ? Is the length of the list above the same length of your DataFrame ?

Comment: Yes, IMCoins, original dataset is with unique IDs, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response! Yep, it helped, but I had to modify the solution because cell with JSON included list of JSONs (in original post). Thank you a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we do not have the original data, I had to recreate it, and suppose it would be formatted like this. Doing `pd.DataFrame(data)` on such objects resulted in the same data in your image.

But then, I properly use `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` and it worked. I just cannot wrap my head around the `meta_prefix` argument that is supposed to strip the name of the key if I ask it to ('meaning, avoiding that 'id' becomes 'items.id'). But since I couldn't make it work, I just made a function that iterates over the columns and rename them properly.

**EDIT** : Since the `items` key are `str` and not `dict`, the only solution I see is to convert all the strings into dictionary. I encountered the very same problem a while ago, and couldn't find another solution. I benchmarked it heavily at the time, and it was pretty fast overall though. See updated code.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [
    {
        'player_id' : 'id1',
        'items' : '{"id" : "item1", "xp" : "27097", "lvl" : "26", "items":[]}'
    },
    {
        'player_id' : 'id2',
        'items' : '{"id":"item2","xp":"40650","lvl":"26","items":[]}'
    },
    {
        'player_id' : 'id3',
        'items' : '{"id":"item3","xp":"33900","lvl":"26","items":["item1", "item2", "item3"]}'
    }
]

for idx in range(len(data)):
    data[idx]['items'] = json.loads(data[idx]['items'])

df = json_normalize(data, meta='items')
#  player_id items.id items.xp items.lvl            items.items
#0       id1    item1    27097        26                     []
#1       id2    item2    40650        26                     []
#2       id3    item3    33900        26  [item1, item2, item3]

prefix = 'items.'
df.columns = [col[len(prefix):] if col.startswith(prefix) else col for col in df.columns]

print(df)
#   player_id     id     xp lvl                  items
# 0       id1  item1  27097  26                     []
# 1       id2  item2  40650  26                     []
# 2       id3  item3  33900  26  [item1, item2, item3]
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but it does not work because data in pandas cells stored as string and this is the only way I can work with this data

Comment: @Jake_A1997 Do you mean that the dictionnary inside `items` is a string ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Data in items is stored as string

Comment: @Jake_A1997 Well, I have good and bad news. Read my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have answer here. Part 1 I recreate the data, Part 2 I answer the question

## PART 1 - Create the Dataset

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
row_1 = "[{'id':'item1','xp':'27097','lvl':'26','items':[]}]"
row_2 = "[{'id':'item2','xp':'40650','lvl':'12','items':[]}]"
row_3 = "[{'id':'item3','xp':'33900','lvl':'45','items':['item1', 'item2', 'item3']}]"

data = {"My Dict":[row_1, row_2, row_3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

Out [1]:
    My Dict
0   [{'id':'item1','xp':'27097','lvl':'26','items'...
1   [{'id':'item2','xp':'40650','lvl':'12','items'...
2   [{'id':'item3','xp':'33900','lvl':'45','items'...
```

## PART 2 - turn this Series of Dict into a Dataframe

```py
In [2]:
from ast import literal_eval

my_list = df['My Dict'].tolist()

list_of_dict = []
## Get a list of dict instead of a list of list of dict 
for elem in my_list:
    my_dict = literal_eval(elem)[0]
    list_of_dict.append(my_dict)

## Turn this list of dict into 1 Dict
new_dict = {}
for item in list_of_dict:
    name = item.pop('id')
    new_dict[name] = item  



## Create a dataframe from this dict 
my_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict).T.reset_index()
my_df

Out [2]:
    index      items                lvl     xp
0   item1   []                      26      27097
1   item2   []                      12      40650
2   item3   [item1, item2, item3]   45      33900
```

Comment: @Jake_A1997 Has this solve your issue? Are you still struggling with it ?

Comment: Hello! Yep, this is defenetly a good solution, and more understandable for me, but I used IMCoins's solution because he posted it a bit earlier. Thank you a lot for your time, I appreciate your help, I wish I could add you points